# Python API client for Elastic Search: can't connect due to Connection timed out

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am working with the Python API client for Elastic Search and I am trying to connect to it.

I create the client like this:

```py
def setup_es():
    ES_USER = os.getenv("ES_USER")
    ES_PASS = os.getenv("ES_PASS")
    print(f"Setting up ES with HOST={ES_HOST}, USER={ES_USER}, PASS={ES_PASS}")
    return Elasticsearch([ES_HOST], basic_auth=(ES_USER, ES_PASS))
```

But whenever I try using the client, I always get a connection timed out error.
For example:

```py
   client.info()
```

or

```py
    client.options(ignore_status=[400,404]).indices.delete(index=MY_INDEX)
```

Always produce:

```py
***_transport.ConnectionTimeout: Connection timed out
```

I know the host, user and password are right. Am I missing something else? Any ideas please?

Comment: What ES_HOST look like?

Comment: @qaziqarta it looks like this https://host:9200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by specifying port `443` in the elastic search host variable.